# Lcation of redux "random" state initialization

Tags: javascript, game, redux

I'm creating [2048](http://2048game.com/) to practice React/Redux. I've got a game board that appropriately shifts, and follows the game rules (it works).

I'm more concerned with my understanding of handling Redux reducers (that seems to be a problematic area for myself, [like when I misunderstood reducer purity by adding randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230608/how-to-unit-test-a-reducer-with-guaranteed-randomness-redux/41230960)).

Initially, I was (incorrectly) having my Board reducer handle randomness. I've updated it so that the Board is currently initialized with 0's and the action creator determines the random values and tiles to place them in (there's a touch of currying and thunk in there).

```
const getNewTileDispatch = (board) => {
  var indicies = getEmptyIndexes(board);
  var toFill = randomFromArray(indicies);
  var value = getNewTileValue();
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TILE',
    x: toFill[0],
    y: toFill[1],
    value: value
  }
}

export const initializeBoard = () => {
  return(dispatch, getState) =>{
    let board = getState().Board.present;
    let minTiles = 2;
    let maxTiles = 5;
    let numTiles = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxTiles-minTiles+1))+minTiles;
    for(let i=0;i<numTiles;i++){
      dispatch(getNewTileDispatch(board));
    }
  }
}
```

I've bound the initializeBoard function to the props, and I'm calling it in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.onkeydown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.props.initializeBoard();
}
```

And here's the board reducer case for good measure:

```
  case 'ADD_TILE':
      var newState = state.slice();
      newState[action.x][action.y]=action.value;
      return newState;
```

Is this an appropriate way to handle "guaranteed randomness" within initialization? Are there any glaring pitfalls that I've overlooked? The code appears to function and "randomly" initialize the board in my browser, while allowing me to unit test the tile placement, and 0-initialization.

[Full code if anyone is interested, it's still fairly rudimentary but I figured I'd start asking earlier rather than later.](https://github.com/Hodrobond/learning2048/tree/master/src)